# "Forgotten" or "forgot" as past participle of "forget"

Tags: verbs, dialects, past-participles

In US and in UK respectively, which is more popular as the past participle of *forget*: *forgotten* or *forgot*? Which is more formal/informal?

Examples:

> I haven't **forgot(ten)** you.
>
> You will not be **forgot(ten)**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OED describes the use of the past participle *forgot* as 'archaic' and 'poetical'.

Comment: THanks! Can OED be used online and free?

Comment: @Tim:Yes, at <http://www.oed.com/>, but it requires subscription. Those in the UK can have free access through their local public libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that Barrie. Do you post your answers from the library?

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ: No, I have direct access from my home computer.

Comment: @Tim: I know, but, as I said, it's free to those in the UK with a public library card.

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically speaking I don't really think *haven't forgot* is a cardinal sin compared to some usages that make it into popular parlance, but it does seem that people [mostly get this one right](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=haven%20%27%20t%20forgot,haven%20%27%20t%20forgotten&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to try ngram, but didn't know which phrases are typical enough for search.

Comment: I wonder if the huge dip in the 1970s was due to the increased consumption of drugs. *"I forgot, man!"*

Comment: @Polynomial: Well, you know what they say - *If you can remember the 70s, you weren't there!* I think we mostly looked at comic books rather than the printed word.

Comment: @Tim: I probably over-use NGram - which isn't all that reliable, I admit. But in a case like this I think it's pretty convincing evidence that the ungrammatical version hasn't exactly shot to prominence.

Comment: Fascinating exchange! Especially the interpretation of the Ngram re the 70s. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking, as an educated southerner and an ESL instructor, I needed to look up the past participle of this word one more time. I interchange between the two without noticing. Sometimes I say, "I have forgot my keys." Sometimes I say, "She's forgotten her money." I would say both are accepted as past participle forms in the Appalachian region and southeastern United States. I heard my doctor say, "You haven't forgot what I told you, have ya?" He has a degree in medicine from Emory University. In my informal speech I often use words that the British stopped using hundreds of years ago. My ancestors wanted to keep a piece of the motherland (Great Britain) so they made a conscious effort to use words and phrases such as "gotten" and "yonder."

Answer (score -2):

"I have forgot your name.",  is the Present Tense in the Future Tense; while, "I have  forgotten your name.," is the Past Tense in the Future Tense.
~ Adin Xol | @aobi_music

Comment: Can you cite some reference-work authority in support of your conclusion in this answer?

Comment: What does the Present/Past Tense in the Future Tense mean? So can I say "He has took an exam"?  Or  is "We have ate out last night" grammatical? No, no, no.